# RadioButtonRenderer with Transparent Background

Tags: c#, winforms, drawing, radio-button

I have a situation where I need to render a radio button to an System.Drawing.Image.

```
System.Drawing.Bitmap bitmap = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(20,16);
using (System.Drawing.Graphics g = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
{                                    
    RadioButtonRenderer.DrawRadioButton(g, new Point(2, 2), RadioButtonState.CheckedPressed);
}
return System.Drawing.Image.FromHbitmap(bitmap.GetHbitmap());
```

This works except that it's drawing the default control-grey as the background.  How can I set this the background color to Transparent?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how your button looks exactly, but using the [Bitmap.MakeTransparent Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8517ckds.aspx) with the grey color should work.

If it is not to your liking, you can try more complex color transformation using the [ColorMatrix Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.colormatrix.aspx):

```
ColorMatrix matrix = new ColorMatrix();

// This will change the image's opacity.
matrix.Matrix33 = 0.5f;

ImageAttributes imgAttrs = new ImageAttributes();
imgAttrs.SetColorMatrix(matrix, ColorMatrixFlag.Default, ColorAdjustType.Bitmap);

g.DrawImage(img, new Rectangle(0, 0, 50, 50), 0, 0, 50, 50, GraphicsUnit.Pixel, imgAttrs);
```